# Problem in swipe between tabs in Use PagerAdapter and ViewPager

Tags: java, android, tabs, viewpage

I use PagerAdapter for ViewPager Adapter without any fragment and just with one layout for Tabs and It is Ok and I can Put my data and ... But I have a problem with swipe ...It is upside down ...I want right to left but Swipe left to right ...

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


  private static final String TAG = "ViewPagerAdapter";

  private Context context;
  private List<PersonItem> personItemList;

  public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, List<PersonItem> personItemList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.personItemList = personItemList;
  }


  @Override
  public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view == object;
  }


  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return personItemList.size();
  }


  @Override
  public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
  }


  @Nullable
  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return personItemList.get(position).getTabTitle();
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    PersonItem personItem = personItemList.get(position);

    ImageView imgPerson = layout.findViewById(R.id.img_person);
    TextView txtPersonContent = layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_person_content);

    if (personItem.getImageUrl() != null) {
      Glide.with(context)
        .load(personItem.getImageUrl())
        .into(imgPerson);
    } else {
      imgPerson.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    if (personItem.getContent() != null) {
      txtPersonContent.setText(personItem.getContent());
    }




    container.addView(layout);

    return layout;
  }
```

---

**ViewPager layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        tools:context=".activity.PersonalityDetailsActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/personality_toolbar"
                layout="@layout/personality_details_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>


            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contextClickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scrollbarSize="30dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabPadding="3dp"
                app:tabPaddingEnd="10dp"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

---

**SetUp ViewPager in activity**

```
//set adapter on View Pager
viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, personItems);
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

---

The OutPut is here :

[The Gif link](https://gifyu.com/image/TIZo)

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: did you see the gif ? I want RTL dir but it is LTR ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

> Step 1. Change the rotation of the View pager,

`viewpager.setRotationY(180);`

> Step 2. Then again change the direction of the fragment container
>   which is the child of viewpager,

`view_pager_fragment_parent_viewgroup.setRotationY(180);`

[For more info](https://mobikul.com/make-viewpager-swipe-rtl/)

Comment: tnx dear, But My child Not RecyclerView ... dear I find it

Comment: use top of View-group  `fragment_layout` instead of `recyclerView`.

Comment: Drae Thnx .. My case I have the layout and set this for it.
```layout.setRotationY(180)``` this is my solution

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` to your `ViewPager` too:

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

And set current page to the last just in case:

```
viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, personItems);
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1); // instead of 0
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: No dear. It is not my solution ...The selector Set in last item and The problem yet

Comment: Oh my bad, if `viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1)` didn't work maybe you could drop it instead, but I could be wrong.

Comment: what I should do dear?

Comment: Sorry I meant if you could try setting the initial current item to the last page. I've just updated my answer.